# A variable updating every time it is changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, variables

i'm trying to create a variable that, everytimes it is changed, checks if the value is a certain amount and updates itself.
I have something like this

```
max = 10
min = 0
var = 1
```

And then some code updating it. Is it any way to keep it updating? It is in a class if it can in some way help.

I tried to put something like

```
if var < min:
 var = min
elif var > max:
 var = max
```

After every block that could change the var, but it is very slow like this.

Comment: An ordinary variable no, but a class field yes, if you make it a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you might approach doing something like this. Although you cannot mess with assignment directly, you can change how *properties* are set and accessed:

```py
class LimitedValue:
    def __init__(self, min, max):
        self.min = min
        self.max = max
        self._value = None

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = min(max(value, self.min), self.max)
```

This could be used as follows:

```py
lv = LimitedValue(0, 100)
lv.value = 50
print(lv.value) # 50
lv.value = 200
print(lv.value) # 100
lv.value = -100
print(lv.value) # 0
```

Depending on the context, this might not be very idiomatic. You could instead just shorten the code you use to constrain `var` to a range `min, max`.

First, I would rename `min` and `max` to something that does not collide with the globals of the same name. Maybe `min_var` and `max_var`. Then, you can simply use

```py
var = min(max_var, max(min_var, var))
```

to constrain `var` to the range you want.

Comment: The suggested use of `min` and `max` functions would be *slower* than what the OP has now; as it guarantees two function calls instead of at most two simple comparisons.

Comment: @chepner my interpretation was that "slow" referred to the process of writing code, not the execution itself. If the variable were "check[ing] if the value is a certain amount and updat[ing] itself," that wouldn't really change the speed. The question seemed to be asking for a way to make writing code more convenient, not a way to make running the code faster.

Comment: A decent editor makes typing that trivial, so it's not an interpretation worth considering as a programming problem.

Comment: @chepner the original post says "it is very slow like this." if the author is noticing an actual performance issue caused by those four lines of code, then their solution idea would do nothing to fix it. i personally don't see any drop-in solution that could fix that problem, beyond computing the limited range more lazily (which introduces its own overhead).